# Is an assigned value not always a variable?

Tags: python, variables, debugging, pycharm

I am trying to debug some Python3.8 code in Pycharm.

The code initially assigns a value something like as follows:

```
self.stats.game_active = False
```

and after the game is started, changes it as follows:

```
self.stats.game_active = True
```

When I am running the debugger, I cannot see if the current value is True or False because I am not seeing the value in the listing of variables.

Am I looking in the wrong place? I thought I was working with a variable. Am I not? If it is not a variable, what is it called? If it is a variable, how do I get it to show in the list of variables in the debugger?

clipovich

Additional information that might be helpful:

```
class GameStats:
    """Track statistics for Alien Invasion."""

    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        """Initialize statistics."""
        self.settings = ai_game.settings
        self.reset_stats()

        # Start Alien Invasion in an inactive state.
        self.game_active = False

def __init__(self):
    """Initialize the game and create game resources."""
    pygame.init()
    self.settings = Settings()

    # Create an instance to store game statistics
    self.stats = GameStats(self)



 def _start_game(self):
        # Reset the game statistics.
        self.stats.reset_stats()
        self.stats.game_active = True
```

Comment: Can you turn this into a _small_ example? This line is in a method and the method is defined on a class. Somewhere you create the class and then call the method. Lets say that line is `my_instance.some_method()`. Then you'd see the variable as `my_instance.stats.game_active`.

Comment: `self` is the variable here.  It is presumably an object which contains a `stats` attribute, which in turn contains a `game_active` attribute.  You'd need to do a bit of drilling down to get to this value in your debugger.

Comment: I added additional code to my original post. Hope that helps.

Comment: So "self" is what I need to be looking for in the variable names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding the variable to a watch list?

As far as I know that should allow you to always see the value of the variable.

-In the Watches pane, click the New Watch button New Watch or press Insert.

-Select one or several items in the Variables pane and drag them to the Watches pane.

or

-Right-click an item in the editor and select Add to Watches.

Comment: I tried but I was not sure what I was looking for. I tried finding self.stats.game_active but the debugger said that it was not a variable. @jasonharper said I should be looking for "self". I guess I was looking for too long of a name. I have several instances of "self". I will try and figure out how to isolate one of them.

Comment: @chadrick `self` is only defined when the variable is in scope. If you step the debugger into a class instance method that typically has `self` as a parameter, only then will it be defined and visible to the debugger.